# Customize the jquery Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am using jqueryDate picker.i want to customize this Datepicker.In this Datepicker Month and year is showing.Like August2014.Here if i click next it will go to next month like previous.

But I want to customize,mean i want to show months in dropdown and Year also i have to show in Dropdown,amd Next and previous function  should be work.Can You Please suggest Me.

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What plugin are you trying to use. If it is this plugin found in [this site](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/). then all you need to do is set the change month and changeyear to true.

```
 $(function() {
            $("YOURSELECTOR" ).datepicker({ 
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true
            });
 });
```

the documentation for the api can be found [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

Comment: Thaks Man Itz Working For Me..:)

Comment: And also i want like this,The calendar needs to autoselect the current day ,mean that today is August 2014, suppose one user want to see 2 month back mean June 2014 .I want create a button ,if i click button ,it will show August 2014.Can you Please Suggest Me...:)

Comment: read thru the api documentation i mentioned. Its fairly easy to understand and well written. Glad to be of help.

Comment: Yeah. @sai..I have gone through this Api....but here which attribute is require for my requirement... M not getting...